# Convert pdf to docx using libreoffice without textbox

Tags: libreoffice, pdftotext

I am working on a service to convert pdf with selectable text, to docx file.
I have used libreoffice to do this with the below command:

```
libreoffice --headless --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to doc:"MS Word 2007 XML"  --outdir /pdfOutput myPdf.pdf
```

The problem is my output file is not in plain text, but textboxes containing editable text.

How can I convert pdf to docx with plain text?

Comment: You have chosen an unsuccessful tool for this task - claims against LibreOffice are inappropriate in this case. Use the Adobe tools (PDF is their brainchild - for example, open the PDF in AcrobatReader and use Select All-Copy), or open the PDF directly in Word (MS says it can convert PDF to text document correctly), or use any OCR (PDF can be made up of document scans and then there is no other way to get the text, only retype it manually from the keyboard), or use some other service (Google offers several ways). It is difficult to work with proprietary formats and not violate any license :-(

Comment: I need to deploy this as part of a containerized service so using MS word is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple tool to perform this operation. You may be able to adapt @Lupp's idea as outlined in the latest edit to [**this post**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/pdf-to-draw-to-writer/13805/10?u=johnsun) to suit your needs.

Comment: I also tried python packages like pdf2docx, PyPDF2 to do this but these ignore the formatting.
I also tried the aspose pdf convertor which gives the best result but is licensed.
I best results were from MS Word but this cannot be containerized.